# Bring implicit parameter into scope from within case class body

Tags: scala

How would I do something like the following (this is obviously a silly example,  but it serves to illustrate my question):

```
trait GetString[T, U] {
  def toString(u: U): String = u.toString
  final def getString(t: T)(implicit f: (T) => U) = toString(f(t))
}

case class MapBoolGetString(name: String) extends GetString[Map[String, String], Boolean] {
  /* This does not work */
  implicit val map2bool = (m: Map[String, String]) => m.contains(name)
}

class Main {
  val test = MapBoolGetString("key")
  test.getString(Map("key" -> "value"))
}
```

This causes the error:

```
No implicit view available from Map[String,String] => Boolean.
```

This is obviously a scope issue; the `map2bool` implicit isn't in scope and, as such, `getString` fails.

Is there a way I can somehow bring this into scope? The reason I put it in the body of `MapBoolGetString` is because I want it to rely on the `name` argument to the constructor within `map2bool`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `import` members of instances in Scala to bring them into scope, and they keep implicitness:

```
val test = MapBoolGetString("key")
import test.map2bool
test.getString(Map("key" -> "value"))
```

As a side note, there's no reason to define both `toString` and `getString`; if you pass something other than `U` to `toString`, Scala will look for implicit conversions in scope automatically.

> Is there any way you can think of to achieve this w/o needing an explicit import statement? I'd love if it were some how part of the instantiating of a MapBoolGetString.

Not really, but if you only need a single implicit, you could do this:

```
case class MapBoolGetString(name: String) extends GetString[Map[String, String], Boolean] with Map[String, String] => Boolean {
  def apply(m: Map[String, String]) = m.contains(name)
}

// in Main
implicit val test = MapBoolGetString("key")
test.getString(Map("key" -> "value"))
```

Comment: Is there any way you can think of to achieve this w/o needing an explicit import statement? I'd love if it were some how part of the instantiating of a `MapBoolGetString`.